# can not load data to combo box in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I try to load combo box content from database. But when I run the code I get undefined variable message. What I did is load data from the database table and in the model then use them in controller to send an array of data to view.

Here is the controller method

```
public function loadcombo(){

       //Calling the getcombo_titel() function to get the arr of titles. Model already loaded.
        $arrStates = $this->dataOperateModel->getcombo_titel();
        print_r($arrStates);
        echo 'hiii';
        //Getting the final array in the form which I will be using for the form helper to create a dropdown.
        foreach ($arrStates as $job_name) {
            $arrFinal[$job_name->title] = $job_name->title;
        }

        $data['job_name'] = $arrFinal;
        $data['main_content']='home/welcome_message';
        print_r($arrFinal);

        //$data['states'] = $arrFinal;
        //$data['main_content']='user/index_view';
        //Passing $data to the view, so that we can get the states as an array inside the view.
        $this->load->view('layout',$data);


        }
```

Here is code in view

```
 <div class="content" id="desc" >Job title</div> <div id="cont" class="content">

                   <?php echo form_dropdown('job_name',$job_name); ?>
 </div>
```

In the error it says `"Undefined variable: job_name"`

Here is the code for the model

```
 public function getcombo_titel(){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM combo_jobtitle");

        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        }
   }
```

Can anybody tell, where I have done the mistake?

Comment: make sure your have datas in `$arrStates` ....

Answer (score 0):

problem was in the sql query. I had mispelled the word `tittle`. sorry guys.

Comment: Ironically, mispelled yet another way in your answer.